Getting Randomly 30+ seconds Delay
When i make API request, sometimes i get unusual response times. More specifically 30+ second delay. After some troubleshooting, i got that Transfer Start or (TTFB) takes upto 30+ seconds randomly. The delay time is always the same (30+s).
What could be the reason or how to debug this further. In local environment it never happens.


Probably need to benchmark the remote computer your backend runs on because some process might be slow to start or too much things happening maybe?

answering your question depends on whether you're local or not, because it's easier to debug the problem locally and on your screenshot i can't see the domain very well. in short, either the problem comes from the database (the server), in which case you need to refactor the code, or the problem comes from the internet connection or from your machine, which is probably slow. try to fix these problems and let me know if it's worked. i'll keep an ear out for any problems.

You can check your boot times and sql query exec times with barryvdh/laravel-debugbar.
If your problem in your code you can debug with that. But the problem may also be server-related. First, you can analyze whether it is not code-related and then examine the server separately.

But is it a good idea to use the package in production ?

Yes, package jus working on debug Mode. You can define debug mode as true only on your own IP address.
